# Customize style of Jupyter Notebooks in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'd like to be able to remove the line above all of my code cells with the green triangle and the capital M. Having it above each code cell takes up lots of vertical space. I'd also like to be able to have all the blue lines between the gray, like in the [visual studio code working with jupyter example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_setting-up-your-environment)

I'm able to navigate to the vscode-jupyter extensions settings panel but couldn't figure out if there was a setting for this.

The main repo is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter but I thought I'd start with a post here!

Thanks

[image: Screenshot of Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to hide the cell toolbar in the upcoming native notebooks interface, which you can currently preview by installing the Jupyter extension in VS Code Insiders, using this setting:

```
"notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
  "default": "hidden"
},
```

Comment: Thanks! For additional information people can see discussion in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6024